# Where is the unresolved path of a Hapi Request?

Tags: hapi.js

Given this route config:

```
server.route
method: 'GET'
path: "/app/usage/{id}"
handler: (req, reply) ->
  ...
```

Is there a way to programmatically get the unresolved path /app/usage/{id} from the request object in a prehandler? I know how to get the resolved path e.g. /app/usage/1234, but I would like the unresolved path (ideally without having to reconstruct it with string manipulation).

```
server.ext 'onPreHandler', (request, reply) ->
  resolvedPath = request.path
  unresolvedPath = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "unresolved path", I'll presume you mean the `path` option specified when creating a route using `server.route(options)`?

The entry from the routing table for the route that gets matched to a request is placed in `request.route` for your inspection:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/app/usage/{id}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        const route = request.route;
        const routePath = route.path;  // '/app/usage/{id}'

        reply('hello')
    }
});
```

It's available throughout the [request lifecycle](http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle), so you can fetch it in an `onPreHandler` extension function too:

```
server.ext('onPreHandler', function (request, reply) {

    const route = request.route;
    const routePath = route.path;  // Whatever your route path is for the request

    reply.continue();
});
```

**NOTE** Be aware that you can't view `request.route.path` inside an `onRequest` extension function, because this is called before a route is matched. From the [relevant section in the API docs](http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle):

> - `onRequest` extension point
>
>   - `request.route` is not yet populated at this point.
> - Lookup route using request path
> - ...